# более 600 или больше 600

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: более 600 предметов или больше 600

Answer (score 2):

Если речь идёт о *неопределённом* количестве, заведомо большем 600 (*Более 600 предметов было конфисковано.*), то варианты отличаются лишь степенью формальности ("больше" соответствует разговорному стилю). Если же выражение используется для обозначения точного граничного значения (*Больше 600 предметов ввозить не разрешается /601 уже нельзя/.*), вариант "больше" уместен и в формальных случаях.